# How long until idle timeout changes take effect on an AWS load balancer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, elastic-load-balancer

I'm getting 504 errors from my elastic beanstalk application. I believe that the requests on the backend are taking too long and the loadbalancer is returning a 504 to the client. I tried up'ing the idle timeout from 60 seconds to 120 seconds on the load balancer, but it still seems to be timing out after 60 seconds. Is there anything else I need to do in order for that to take effect, or is it just a matter of time?

[image]

Comment: can you attach a screen shot of your elb configuration ?

Comment: what all do you want to see?

Comment: I've attached a picture

Comment: I think I may have determined from the ELB logs that the 504 is coming from the server, not the load balancer. Continuing to investigate...

Comment: nice , good luck with your debugging :)

Comment: @AmitKhandelwal thanks for assist. I figured out my issue and posted the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I figured out the issue. While this doesn't exactly answer my original question (how long it takes until ELB timeout changes take effect), it did fix the issue I was experiencing.

Basically, you need to configure the nginx proxy to up the timeouts:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/47169533/2460073

Side note - the logs from the loadbalancer were helpful to show that both the `BackendStatusCode` and `ElbStatusCode` where 504. This revealed that was in fact the application server returning a `504`.

Comment: Also, checking the response headers is usually very valuable.  Seeing `Server: nginx` would rule out the balancer as throwing the error.

Comment: Doesn't necessarily rule out the balancer as throwing the error. I've seen `502 Bad Gateway` coming from the balancer when the back end server closes the connection, but doesn't send any response headers/bytes. (In this case it was a bug in the nodejs app, but nonetheless).

Comment: If the server doesn't send any response headers, the balancer wouldn't set `Server: nginx` in the response.

Comment: Oh - I see what you're saying now. Thanks for that tidbit!